# Angular isState - how to make comparision inside ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

THE SITUATION:

Hello guys.
I am using isState for my angular app.

This is the documentation page:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.filter:isState

I have to make a simple check, inside ng-if, to see if the state is equal 'A' or 'B'.

THE CODE:

This is the list that contain the navigation:
(i should make the check inside that ng-if)

```
<ul class="menu-extra list-inline pull-right" ng-if="is_master' | isState ">

</ul>
```

THE QUESTION:

How can i make a comparision, inside the ng-if, to check if the state is equal a certain state OR a certain another state?

Thank you!

Comment: I think, you missed initial quote before `is_master`. It should be `ng-if="'is_master' | isState"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the filter expressions into parenthesis and OR them:

```
ng-if="('is_A' | isState) || ('is_B' | isState)"
```